# Dot appended to the end of MQ message when passing it from C# .Net application to IBM MQ

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I am passing message from C# .NET 4.0 to MQ version: 7.5.0.5 . Snippet of the code

```
queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(strQueueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

queueMessage = new MQMessage();

queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
queueMessage.MessageType = 8;

queueMessage.CharacterSet = 1208; 

queueMessage.WriteUTF(message);

queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
messageWrittenSuccessfully = true;
queue.Close();
```

I am getting the message with character followed by dot
C.E.R.1.2.3.4. rather than CER1234

not sure if this is related to encoding or CCIS issue.

Comment: Are you sure it is a dot - period (char 46  x2D ) .    It could be your string viewer is putting a dot for another non printable character and the dot is not a decimal 46 character.   I wonder if you would see this same behavior on 2byte or 8 byte strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your CharacterSet to 437 for ASCII.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030277/putting-message-in-websphere-mq-via-c-sharp-has-different-data-length-than-manua) is a nice long explanation of your issue.

Also, you should be using the MQ defines for MessageType:

```
queueMessage.MessageType = MQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;
```